# Limiting number of character on println() statement in Java

Tags: java, formatting, string-formatting

I'm trying to implement a method which takes a string of text and a column 
width and outputs the text, each line limited to the column width.

```
public void wrapText(String text, int width)
{
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

For example, calling the method with the text:

```
Triometric creates unique end user monitoring products for high-value Web 
  applications, and offers unrivalled expertise in performance consulting.
```

with column width 20 would result in the following output:

```
Triometric creates  
unique end user  
monitoring products  
for high-value Web  
applications, and  
offers unrivalled  
expertise in  
performance  
consulting.
```

Comment: Iterate the chars of the string and add a `\n` after every `width`th one

Comment: Mm, not so easy @kocko. That could result in a line-break in the middle of a word!

Comment: That being said, @user3182511, what would happen if `width` were smaller than a word length? Would there be a hyphen inserted as the 20th character in a line, then the rest of the line continued?

Comment: what if a word itself is longer than 20 chars?

Comment: you need to split the string at every whitespace  (`\w`) into words and ouptut them, controlling both linelength and wordlength. You should add some kind of "border" which is allowed to overlap until a word is actually broken on the next line.

Comment: If 1 word is longer than 20 chars then we can allow it but other wise no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
public static void wrapText(String text, int width) {
    int count = 0;

    for (String word : text.split("\\s+")) {
        if (count + word.length() >= width) {
            System.out.println();
            count = 0;
        }

        System.out.print(word);
        System.out.print(' ');

        count += word.length() + 1;
    }
}
```

Although there are still cases where the result of the method is not clear (for example, if the length of an individual word is greater than `width`). The code above will simply print such a word on its own line.

Comment: +1 Any particular reason not to use `for (String s : split) {...`?

Comment: @tobias_k Yes, I think that would be better. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by splitting the String at whitelines and then printing word by word, like this:

```
public static void wrapText(String text, int width) throws Exception {
    String[] words = text.split(" ");
    int acsize = 0;
    for (String word : words) {

        if (word.length() > width) {
            throw new Exception("Word longer than with!");
        }
        if (acsize + word.length() <= width) {
            System.out.print(word + " ");
            acsize += word.length() + 1;
        } else {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print(word + " ");
            acsize = word.length() + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

The exception could be just removed, if you want to print words longer than width, like you said in you last comment.